How to prevent leaking batteries in multimeters
I'm having issues with leaking alkaline batteries in my multimeters (Fluke 17B and Fluke 325).
The batteries were from reputable brands.
I think the solution for this problem may pass by a periodic inspection of battery state.
Can you help me with the periodicity of the inspection in order to avoid this problem?

yes ... check monthly

Duracells have a reputation for leaking (which is my experience also). At least use a different brand. Monthly inspection sounds about right in any case,

The most advertised brands have a tendency to leak. I've had good results with Panasonic batteries which have slightly less capacity than the "popular" brands. Checking batteries monthly is a good idea.

'Check monthly' seems to be a popular theme, but what are we checking for? The appearance of ooze is a bit late, unless we are saying that it gets worse so slowly that a month of it is 'not too bad'. Cell voltage? Is there a voltage above which ooze does not appear?

@Neil_UK I think you're asking the question I'd assume OP wants to ask (AmssmA, would you confirm?) anyways. I think yes, there might be some voltage under load that you'd probably be pretty safe (I think the leakage mechanism is due to hydrogen gas buildup inside the cell, so actually an effect of discharge). But then again, these being measurement equipment, I'd assume this is actually already covered by the "low battery" warning the device has itself.

As I think about it, the community I'd ask about low-leakage-probability battery choices ("how do I recognize whether an AA battery is likely to leak inside my device?") would be the retrocomputing people. Before one goes and asks on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com , I'd definitely first politely ask on their meta site whether that would be on-topic.

Energizer's battery manufacturer is so confident that they guarantee to replace the damaged device.

I've had Duracell and Panasonic batteries leak, damaging my wall clocks and equipments. I'd recommend checking batteries every 15 days. For peace of mind, I use Energizer Li-FeS2 batteries on expensive equipments like LCR meters and multimeters. They cost about 6 times more than Duracell, have a 25-year shelf life, a better power density, buy output 1.8V rather than 1.5V. Just beware of short circuits, which can cause fires.

Most reputable brands offer lithium based batteries for the common disposable types (AA, AAA,...). Lithium based batteries are far less likely to leak (I've never had one leak).

(Image source: Energizer Europe)
Image for illustration, other manufacturers offer them as well...
They're more expensive then alkaline batteries, but in low power applications such as remote controls and multimeters you can basically install them, forget about them, keep using them until depleted and they won't have leaked...
